# updateOne with multiple parameter set to true not working in mongodb 3.6.1

Tags: mongodb

We upgraded to a newer db running Mongo 3.6.18 and existing code has stopped working.

(After countless hours of soul searching and nail biting...) I have traced it to the following code:

```
    $this->st_manager->update_record(
                    [
                        'user_id'       => $driverId,
                        'Display_lng'   => $item['lng'], 
                        'Display_lat'   => $item['lat'],
                    ], [
                        '$set' => $update_params,
                    ], [
                        'upsert'        => false,
                        'multiple'      => true,
                    ]
                );
```

My update_record code is simply this:

```
    public function update_record( $findquery, $newdata, $option ) {
    $this->collection->updateOne( $findquery, $newdata, $option );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.updateOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) doesn't have `multiple` option, as it's intended to update only *one* document.

If you want to update multiple documents use [`.updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) instead.

Note that `.updateMany()` doesn't need the option `multiple` to be passed (and doesn't accept it), as it's already intended to update multiple documents.

Comment: That worked for me. Not sure why my previous developer had it in there though with updateOne. Plus it used to work fine before upgrade to 3.6. Weird. Thanks again anyway.